# Rivets.js Cart.js Shopify Product Not removing/updating on cart

Tags: javascript, shopify, rivets.js

I have a cart page that is using rivets.js, cart.js and uses shopify.

My issue is none of the remove, qty increase/decrease buttons are working on the cart page.

Below is the code that I'm using.
The display is working as expected. It shows the qty, price, item name, description etc.

```
<div data-cart-view="data-cart-view">

  <div class="cart-info cart-info--mobile">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid__item one-third">

        <strong data-cart-render="item_count">{{ cart.items.size }}</strong>

      <small>recommendations</small>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__item one-third">
        <strong data-cart-render="item_count"></strong>
      <small>pills per pack</small>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__item one-third cart-total">
      <strong>$ <span rv-html="cart.total_price | customcurrency"></span></strong>
      <small>per month</small>
    </div>
  </div>

  </div>



  <div rv-each-item="cart.items" class="cart-item grid">
    {% include 'bold-cart-item' with item %}
    <ul class="hide">
      <li rv-each-property="item.propertyArray < properties"  rv-data-id="property.name" rv-data-name="property.value" class="property-counter"></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="grid__item one-sixth">
      <img rv-src="item.image | productImageSize '250x250'">
    </div>


    <span rv-html="index | plus 1"></span>

    <div class="grid__item five-sixths"> 
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="grid__item large--four-sixths two-thirds">
          <h3 rv-text="item.title"></h3>
          <div class="cart-quantity" rv-data-id="item.title">
            <a href="#" rv-data-cart-update="index | plus 1" rv-data-cart-quantity="item.quantity | minus 1">-</a>
            <div class="qty"><span class="num" rv-text="item.quantity"></span> <span class="tablet">tablet</span></div>
            <a href="#" rv-data-cart-update="index | plus 1" rv-data-cart-quantity="item.quantity | plus 1">+</a>

            <span class="dailydose">Suggested daily dose</span>
          </div>


          {{ bold_item_properties }}
          {{ bold_recurring_desc }}
          {{ bold_item_price }}
        </div>
        <div class="grid__item large--two-sixths one-third text-right">
          <div class="item-price">
            <div class="price">$<span rv-html="item.line_price | customcurrency"></span></div>
            {% comment %}<td rv-html="item.line_price | money Currency.currentCurrency"></td>{% endcomment %}
            <small>per month</small>
          </div>
          <a href="#" rv-data-cart-remove="index | plus 1"  class="item-remove">&times;</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


<div class="cart-info cart-info--desktop">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid__item one-third">
        {% comment %} <strong data-cart-render="item_count"></strong>{% endcomment %} 
      <strong>{{ cart.items.size }}</strong>
      <small>recommendations</small>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__item one-third">
        <strong data-cart-render="item_count"></strong>
      <small>pills per pack</small>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__item one-third cart-total">
      <strong>$<span rv-html="cart.total_price | customcurrency"></span></strong>
      <small>per month</small>
    </div>
  </div>

  </div>

  </div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.
It is also using Bold as the recurring subscription app.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you see any errors in your developer console?

Comment: @DavidR nope. no errors at all.

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out?

Comment: No sorry. Had to do my own thing. Just wondering if you checked if rivets.js was initiated.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue, and couldn't figure out the solution. I saw the console give an error saying that the ajax functions are not defined in the jQuery. Turns out I was using the *slim* version, which doesn't include the ajax stuff.

Opted in and used the regular [minified version](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js) and now, both the remove button and the quantity selector seem to be working fine.